# Optimal method to generate an n-digit string with randrange?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that generates an n-digit string. The output is used to build randomly named directories to store data. I need to be able to pass n to the function while remaining efficient.

```
import random


def rand(n):
    output = random.randrange(10**(n - 1), 10**n)
    return output
```

Is there a better or alternative approach to build variable-length strings of random integers in Python?

Comment: How big can `n` be, realistically? (From your expectation of how this would be used.)  This seems pretty quick as it is.

Comment: For my use, only 20 digits. It's more about the function being ideal than a problem of resources. I haven't been able to find a better approach that is as readable. Though sometimes a separate set of eyes sees an obvious alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks clean and is *very* fast, even for large *n* (say 10,000+).

This is  because *a)* no range object is actually ever created and *b)* random values are produced on *bit* level.

With two arguments, [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) basically works like this:

```
def randrange(a, b):
    return a + _randbelow(b-a)
```

`_randbelow(n)` then uses [`getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits) to produce an integer with `n.bit_length()` random bits that is smaller than `n`.

---

This said, for your use case you might consider using the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module, especially [tempfile.mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp).

Comment: Normally I would use the tempfile module but this project has a specific goal which requires a different approach. Thank you for the input and explanation.